# What is causing this Ubuntu boot failure?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Got this screen, it doesn't react.
I cannot move further at all.

[image]

I've searched extensively online, but didn't didn't find anything helpful.

I thought it's a connectivity issue between my screen and host, so unplugged my screen from the host and replugged in.

Then restarted the host machine.
Stuck with the same screen attached here.

I've another image needs to the posted, here's the link, please help! Thanks a lot! http://postimg.org/image/kkub5ysa3/

Comment: You didn't provide the url to the image so we can't inline the screenshot.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a **link** to your image and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Comment: I do not get it: is this the screen of the host? Or of a Virtual machine which crashes your whole system?

Comment: This is the screen of the host. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How is Virtualbox connected to this problem, then?

Comment: I was just going to add one more picture here. Because I was running RHEL5 inside this Ubuntu host, but got this error before I restarted the Ubuntu host. http://postimg.org/image/kkub5ysa3/ Please help me post it since I don't have enough reputation to do so. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you tried to boot with default kernel?

Comment: I've rebooted and got the same error screen. @FranciscoTapia

Comment: try to break  CTRL + C

Comment: My keyboard and mouse don't have any interaction with the screen now. :( @FranciscoTapia

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet lies in booting from a live distro (a USB with, say, Ubuntu installed), and modify this line,

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

in the file */etc/default/grub*, to look  like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

The nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel not to load video drivers but use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded. If you cannot boot from the USB stick, you may apply the same correction to the USB stick itself, and then later to your HDD.